# Running __import__ resets all globals to None when running tests

Tags: python, import, python-2.7

When I run `__import__` directly or indirectly using `importlib.import_module` ([code](https://github.com/ZyX-I/powerline/blob/fbccc659de6a3baddc784190a819ba61505f17a1/powerline/lib/vcs/__init__.py#L27))

```
python setup.py test
```

procudes `TypeError` or similar error indicating that `NoneType` object cannot do something. Some exploration revealed that `None` appears immediately after `importlib` call: all globals defined in module now got assigned this value. This does not happen if I am not running tests. More, this does not happen if I am importing from another directory (while importing modules like `powerline.lib.vcs.git` from `__init__.py` file that is a file for `powerline.lib.vcs` module this behavior is seen, but not when importing from `powerline.lib.vcs_modules` with empty `__init__.py`).

Tests are done by `setuptools` using `unittest` with test suite in separate `tests` directory. Python version is `2.7.3-r2` (`-r2` stands for ebuild revision). Error output can be seen [here](https://travis-ci.org/ZyX-I/powerline/jobs/5021164).

How to fix this behavior?

More strange data: I was able to create two directories such that `diff -r --brief ~/.vam/powerline-{old,new}` returns no changes (old = error, new = recloned, no error) and `diff -u <(ls -laR) <(cd ../powerline-new && ls -laR)` reports only changes in some directory modification times, but for powerline-old it fails and for powerline-new it does not. Exchanging directories locations does not change the result. Neither does copying both directories with `cp -r` in other location or doing `tar c`, then `tar x`.

Ah, and fresh clone in *travis* virtual machine also [shows](https://travis-ci.org/ZyX-I/powerline/jobs/5022734) this weird error.

Any ideas what can this mean? Where can state be hold to distinguish between these directories?

Comment: Can you give us some example code to reproduce this?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer It is impossible to reproduce this with just example code, you need at least a project. I am currently unable to reduce powerline. If I remove everything that seems unrelated tests do not fail.

Comment: More interesting details: it fails with this error on orinigal repository and in travis clone, but not in fresh clone on my system.